# codeigniter sitemap not working

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, syntax-error, sitemap

I was creating a sitemap in codeignite. But i am facing some error with sitemap. Anyone tell me what is error.

**Controller:-**

```
 public function sitemap()
 {
     header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
     $this->load->view("sitemap");        
 }
```

**View:-**

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>    
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">    
   <url>    
      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>    
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>    
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>    
      <priority>0.8</priority>    
   </url>    
</urlset>
```

**error:-**

> XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
>       Location: http://localhost/project/index.php/sitemap.xml
>       Line Number 2, Column 1:
>       ^

Comment: change the file name from `sitemap.xml` to `sitemap.php`

Comment: i am developing sitemap in codeigniter in this framework accept only .php so i have already created sitemap.php

Answer (score 1):

controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

public function sitemap()
{
    header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
    $this->load->view("sitemap");        
}
}
```

view

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>    
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">    
  <url>    
   <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>    
   <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>    
   <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>    
   <priority>0.8</priority>    
 </url>    
</urlset>
```

page is loading fine with me... I was only able to replicate the error message when I saved it as `sitemap.xml` instead of `sitemap.php`

Comment: post as comment not an answer!

Comment: editing the answer to show the controller and view i used to display what you want...

Answer (score 1):

First of all :

remove this

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
```

and Add the following line on top of the /view/sitemap.php page

```
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' ?>
```

Finally,
To call the sitemap page as .xml
add the following line in /config/routes.php

```
$route['controller_name/sitemap\.xml'] = "controller_name/sitemap";
```

Hope this would help you.